# How to add a custom validation method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

As we know that in Laravel, we can validate a request by $request->validate() method that automatically redirect the user if validation failed.
I am trying to develop a function with a similar feature only difference is that, instead of redirecting the user, this function will send a JSON response on validation failure.

Here is my code

```
<?php 

namespace App\Libs;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as RequestCore;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class Request extends RequestCore {

    public function validateAjax($data){
        $input = $this->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input,$data);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
           return response()->json([
               "errors" => $validator->errors(),
               "message" => "Invalid Input"
           ], 401); 
        }
       
        return true;
    }
}
```

Problem is, when i run the code, It doesn't stop on error. What am i missing?

Comment: This is how the validation should already work out of the box. What are you using to send your ajax request? Also, please can show the validation rules and explain which are not failing when they should.

Answer (score 0):

You should make new Request class (php artisan make:request ExampleRequest). And after add this function in that class for JSON response

```
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();

        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'errors' => $errors], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        );
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how to  this method will be invoked